# Laravel validate error

Tags: php, laravel

This is the error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Call to
>   undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()

This is my code

```
$validator = Validator::make($userdata,$rules);

if( $validator->fails() )
{
    return View::make('default::partials.user.getregistration')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

What can this be?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe that you probably have

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
```

in your file.  (Your IDE probably thought it was being helpful.)  To use the static `::` call, `Validator` should be aliased to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator`. (The \app\config\app.php file does this for you by default.)

Chances are good that changing the use statement to

```
use \Validator;
```

will fix things.

Answer (score 5):

Add this below namespace:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The only explanation is that you need to use the classes you are calling in the code @NicoHaase

Comment: @Mrunali, was the reference a bad reference? I just added more content to your awnser that wasn't on the 1st one..

Answer (score 2):

Can you please go to your *app/config/app.php* and check whether

```
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider
```

is available or not.
If not then just add this line and check if the problem is solved or not.
Hope it will help you.