# laravel 7 ; Unable to validate multiple files

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i am trying to validate a multi file array for a larvel 7 project

i followed [this guide:](https://www.mynotepaper.com/laravel-upload-multiple-images-and-files-with-validation) that suggest using the function:

```
Validator::make()
```

However my controller is unable to locate this method and i cannot find it anywhere:

I did use this at the top of my controller:

```
use \Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
```

Below is the method i used on my controller

```
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
    {

 $input = $request->all();

          $validator = Validator::make(
                $input,
                [
                    'images.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp|max:20000'
                ],[
                    'images.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
                    'images.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg,png and bmp images are allowed',
                    'images.*.max' => 'Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an image is 20MB',
                ]
            );

}
```

**This is the Error i get:**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()
```

Any suggestions on how to validate multiple files/Images in Laravel 7 would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? did you use $validator->validate() after this?

Comment: HI @UzairRiaz - first problem. i cannot even find the validate::make function

Comment: hi @UzairRiaz - this is the error i get : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()

Comment: try `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`.

Comment: Thanks @UzairRiaz. its. the right one. it worked. could you perhaps answer this as a question so that i can mark it correclty. it might then help other people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel validate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328850/laravel-validate-error)

Comment: @theSeeker you can close it because it has duplicate.

Comment: @theSeeker i posted it as the answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` function exists in `Validator` facade. You can use it like so `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`